# Visual Studio Code problem at compiling and running (wrong path)

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, path, include

I've been really patient with visual studio code since this morning as I was going back into the cold bath that is C++. While it was seemingly good at first, it all went to S**T when I tried organizing my files.

***Here is a description of my situation***

I have a really simple arborescence

```
Folder\header\thisHeader.h
Folder\source\thisHeader.cpp
```

in the **thisHeader.h** file, we can find

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int somefunction()
{
    printf("5 hours later, coffee did not work and hope is looking grim");
    return 0;
}
```

while in the **thisHeader.cpp** file, we have the following

```
#include "F/headers/thisHeader.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    somefunction();
}
```

Running those fairly easy lines will give me a path error to **thisHeader.h** even though it IS the path needed. I have tried running the code into one file and it does compile.
I would LOVE some help because quite frankly, this problem has cost me my day even though I'm sure its answer is bloody simple.

The three things I would presume are posing some compiling threats are:

1. My path to the header
2. My file organization (for some dark reasons?)
3. My damned IQ and live choices

Comment: This looks like just insufficient attention to detail in the filename.  `F` is not the same as `Folder` (or was that supposed to be `F:` a drive letter?)  `headers` is not the same as `header`.  Besides simple typos, you don't seem to be using paths relative to the file doing the `#include`.... most likely you should have `#include "../header/thisHeader.h"`.    And then to top it all off, function bodies don't belong in header files unless they are `inline` or `template`s

Comment: Yeah I figured my path was all wrong and was missing the ../ at the beginning in order to back down one directory before going into **headers**. My typos were not really typos. I just wrote my question without translating well enough. Thanks man!